# I always fail to use the correct conditional construction!

Tags: conditional-constructions

Which  one of the following options are correct? I think the second one  is correct because it is about past and we need third conditional. Is it right?

> 1. Curfews were a big part of my childhood and I was supposed to be at home at a specific time. If I **didn’t observe** the rule then the
>    punishment **would be** getting grounded for a week
> 2. Curfews were a big part of my childhood and I was supposed to be at home at a specific time. If I **hadn't observed** the rule then the
>    punishment **would have been** getting grounded for a week

Comment: In my view, you are not talking about a hypothetical situation in the past, but a rule in the past. I think you should have the first condition in the past. so I think the first sentence as future in the past could be true. I think the second and the third condition do not fit here.

Comment: I think that both of these are good English, but the first one suggests that you didn't observe the rule sometimes, while the second suggests that you always observed the rule.  That said, since the punishment was obviously known it's fair to present it in the imperfect tense - "the punishment was getting grounded for a week" or less ambiguously "the punishment was that I would be grounded for a week".